# How to show recommendation to lite version app in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

Recently found a new feature in the play store, some apps like Facebook and Opera listing page shows the option to navigate to their lite version app. This is featured in this post; please refer this(https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/04/24/play-store-now-recommending-lite-apps-users/). I searched the google play console FAQs and other forums but couldn't find any available resources related to the topic, Whats the process to add this feature to my app's listing page? Please help me with valuable suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this isn't something you can choose to do as a developer. Google Play does this feature for you.

- If you have Google Play Business Development partner you could try asking them
- If you don't you could try asking Play Console support using the help menu in the Play Console

Comment: Thanks for the info @Nick Fortescue